# Show that A can be covered by finitely many closed subintervals $J_1, ..., J_2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let A be a closed bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

**Question:** How do I show that A can be covered by finitely many closed subintervals $J_1, ..., J_2$, each of at most length $\epsilon$.

**Presumed answer:** We have $A = [a,b]$. Pick n the first integer that is larger than $\dfrac{|b-a|}{\epsilon}$ and let $J_i = [a + (i - 1)\epsilon, a + i\epsilon]$, then we have that $A \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n}J_i$.

Is this correct?

Comment: yes it is correct.

Comment: Will $n$ be an integer ?Take note that You are summing over $n$

Comment: @Maths_Is_Fun is this better?

Comment: yes it is okay to take such $n$

Comment: Let $I$ be closed bounded interval. The set of intervals of type $(x-\epsilon/2,x+\epsilon/2)$ for $x\in I $ form an open cover for $I$ and hence by Heine Borel a finite number of them cover $I$. Just change those selected intervals to closed and your job is done.